# Visual Studio 2019 Setup Project - Download prerequisites from the same location

Tags: visual-studio-2019, setup-project, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create an installer using VS 2019 for a .NET Core 3.1 Console App.
It will be installed in a computer without internet and without the .NET Core 3.1 there.

I have added .NET Core Runtime 3.1.x as a Prerequisite in the Prerequisite Dialog.
When I build, its coming up with this error:
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'netcore3coreruntime_x64\dotnet-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe' for item '.NET Core Runtime 3.1.18 (x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

The question is, in my development PC where should I put this file?

Answer (score 0):

Place the installfile "dotnet-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe" in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages\netcore3coreruntime_x64"

And check in the "product.xml" file in same directory, that the key "publickey" is not "0" and is set to "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"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).